# Replacement for <servlet-mapping> in web.xml & Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url-routing

Because my URLs are really complex and each of the parts between the slashes depends on the content of my database, I suppose the  is not sufficient for me. I suppose I need to write some URL parser, which goes through the url parts between the slash and calls some kind of handler.

Is there a way how to write such URL parser, which would get string and return an object, representing the current request, that would replace the ? I only managed to find simple tutorials which use only the url-routing defined by web.xml.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is extremely flexible, so you can customize URL parsing. Take a look on this tutorial http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s11.html, pay attention on DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter. It seems you should study how do they work and override some of the functionality.

But before you are starting, think again. Do you really need this and `@RequestMapping` does not satisfy you? Really, you can use path variable `{myvar}` into the URL pattern definition. The variables may be of different types including enums. I used this and found very convenient. You can for example create `enum MyType ONE, TWO`; define abstract method on enum level and override it for each element. Then you can use path variable  of type `MyType` into the request mapping and call this method directly from the method marked with `@RequesteMapping` annotation.

Comment: Thanks! I will check all of the suggested. The problem of my URLs is the fact, that I need to check each part against the database and on each result depend what will be checked in database next.

Comment: Well, after reading it, I still dont feel it is exactly what I am looking for. How do you then generate URLs for controllers/views? Imagine having controllers AppleContr and PearContr. Each of them has views Public and Edit, and the generated page depends on ID. Then assume, I want to make a link in a template like this: <a href="${link AppleCont:Public,id=123}">...</a>, can I do it somehow?